# Why does face-white (面白い) mean interesting (おもしろい)?

Tags: meaning, etymology

I've been told おもしろい can mean interesting.

おもしろい can apparently be written:【面白い】.

How does 面白 (face-white?) equate to interesting?

Are white faces interesting?

Comment: In the first place, 面 is more like "surface" than "face".